# time on machines change after some time in spite chrony service configured

Tags: linux, rhel, time, ntp, chrony

we have machines in cluster 
before one week we restart the chrony service , and we check the time on all machines

after chrony restart time was ok on all machines

after 2 days we noticed that on some machine we have time diff for more then 1 hour gap

what we see is when we run the chronyd service we see from output : *`Can't synchronise: no selectable sources`*

```
full details

 systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-11-01 19:12:36 UTC; 1 day 15h ago
  Process: 36664 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/chrony-helper update-daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 36660 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/chronyd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 36663 (chronyd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
           └─36663 /usr/sbin/chronyd

Nov 02 20:50:01 server_524,sys65.com chronyd[36663]: Forward time jump detected!
Nov 02 20:50:01 server_524,sys65.com chronyd[36663]: Can't synchronise: no selectable sources
Nov 02 20:53:14 server_524,sys65.com chronyd[36663]: Selected source 193.34.2.90
Nov 02 20:53:14 server_524,sys65.com chronyd[36663]: System clock wrong by -6895.552231 seconds, adjustment started
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

we also performed the following verification's , as explain down

but we not captured the root cause why time was change 
any suggestion what could be the reason ?

```
chronyc -n tracking ; date
Reference ID    : 193.34.2.90 (193.34.2.90)
Stratum         : 7
Ref time (UTC)  : Sun Nov  3 09:23:51 2019
System time     : 2563.336425781 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000040391 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000760717 seconds
Frequency       : 30.168 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +0.016 ppm
Skew            : 0.907 ppm
Root delay      : 0.335443 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.427117 seconds
Update interval : 70.4 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
Sun Nov  3 10:07:29 UTC 2019
```

**we compare hwclock to time on machine**

```
date ; hwclock
Sun Nov  3 10:40:18 UTC 2019
Sun 03 Nov 2019 10:45:39 AM UTC  -0.907261 seconds
```

**the configuration of chrony is:**

```
more /etc/chrony.conf
# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
server 193.34.2.90   iburst

# Ignore stratum in source selection.
stratumweight 0

# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift

# Enable kernel RTC synchronization.
rtcsync

# In first three updates step the system clock instead of slew
# if the adjustment is larger than 10 seconds.
makestep 10 3

# Allow NTP client access from local network.
#allow 192.168/16

# Listen for commands only on localhost.
bindcmdaddress 127.0.0.1
bindcmdaddress ::1

# Serve time even if not synchronized to any NTP server.
#local stratum 10

keyfile /etc/chrony.keys




# Specify the key used as password for chronyc.
commandkey 1

# Generate command key if missing.
generatecommandkey

# Disable logging of client accesses.
noclientlog

# Send a message to syslog if a clock adjustment is larger than 0.5 seconds.
logchange 0.5

logdir /var/log/chrony
log measurements statistics tracking
```

more sanity:

1)

```
 chronyc -n sources
210 Number of sources = 1
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^* 193.34.2.90                   6   6   377    15  +6522ns[  +94us] +/-  603ms
```

2)

```
    timedatectl
          Local time: Sun 2019-11-03 11:01:13 UTC


 Universal time: Sun 2019-11-03 11:01:13 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2019-11-03 11:08:26
       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: yes
      DST active: n/a

Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
         This mode can not be fully supported. It will create various problems
         with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
         time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
         If at all possible, use RTC in UTC by calling
         'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.
```

3)

```
tail -10 measurements.log
2019-11-03 09:20:19 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -8.100e-05  1.460e-04  1.477e-06  3.353e-01  4.268e-01
2019-11-03 09:21:30 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -7.400e-05  1.660e-04  1.477e-06  3.353e-01  4.279e-01
2019-11-03 09:22:40 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -9.400e-05  1.530e-04  1.477e-06  3.353e-01  4.290e-01
2019-11-03 09:23:51 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -3.800e-05  1.810e-04  1.478e-06  3.353e-01  4.300e-01
2019-11-03 09:25:01 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -1.900e-05  2.210e-04  1.477e-06  3.353e-01  4.311e-01
2019-11-03 09:26:11 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -9.500e-05  1.540e-04  1.477e-06  3.353e-01  4.321e-01
2019-11-03 09:27:21 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00  2.880e-04  9.430e-04  1.480e-06  3.353e-01  4.332e-01
2019-11-03 09:28:33 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -1.420e-04  1.500e-04  1.477e-06  3.353e-01  4.342e-01
2019-11-03 09:29:43 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -9.400e-05  1.340e-04  1.479e-06  3.353e-01  4.353e-01
2019-11-03 09:30:53 193.34.2.90     N  6 111 111 1111   6  6 0.00 -1.330e-04  2.190e-04  1.479e-06  3.353e-01  4.364e-01
```

4)

```
# tail -10 statistics.log
2019-11-03 09:25:01 193.34.2.90      5.007e-06  4.996e-06  5.989e-06  3.351e-08  3.524e-07 2.2e-02   5   0   5
2019-11-03 09:26:11 193.34.2.90      2.132e-05  8.896e-05  1.616e-05  4.535e-07  3.464e-06 1.3e+00   6   2   3
2019-11-03 09:27:21 193.34.2.90      4.463e-05  6.743e-06  4.529e-05  3.689e-07  2.964e-06 2.0e-02   5   0   4
2019-11-03 09:28:33 193.34.2.90      5.257e-05  1.377e-04  3.979e-05  9.986e-07  9.823e-06 2.3e-01   6   2   4
2019-11-03 09:29:43 193.34.2.90      4.778e-05  8.748e-05  3.340e-05  1.079e-06  8.638e-06 1.1e-02   5   1   3
==============================================================================================================
   Date (UTC) Time     IP Address    Std dev'n Est offset  Offset sd  Diff freq   Est skew  Stress  Ns  Bs  Nr
==============================================================================================================
2019-11-03 09:30:53 193.34.2.90      4.487e-05  1.285e-04  4.349e-05  1.598e-06  1.385e-05 6.8e-02   5   1   4
2019-11-03 09:32:03 193.34.2.90      3.720e-05  8.503e-05  3.075e-05  1.381e-06  2.748e-06 8.3e-03   5   0   5
```

5)

```
# tail -10 tracking.log
2019-11-03 09:25:01 193.34.2.90      7    -30.136      0.386  4.996e-06 N  1  5.989e-06 -2.562e+03
2019-11-03 09:26:11 193.34.2.90      7    -30.119      0.581  8.896e-05 N  1  1.616e-05 -2.556e+03
2019-11-03 09:27:21 193.34.2.90      7    -30.081      0.940  6.743e-06 N  1  4.529e-05 -2.550e+03
2019-11-03 09:28:33 193.34.2.90      7    -30.055      1.338  1.377e-04 N  1  3.979e-05 -2.544e+03
2019-11-03 09:29:43 193.34.2.90      7    -29.982      2.099  8.748e-05 N  1  3.340e-05 -2.539e+03
==================================================================================================
   Date (UTC) Time     IP Address   St   Freq ppm   Skew ppm     Offset L Co  Offset sd Rem. corr.
==================================================================================================
2019-11-03 09:30:53 193.34.2.90      7    -29.879      3.249  1.285e-04 N  1  4.349e-05 -2.533e+03
2019-11-03 09:32:03 193.34.2.90      7    -28.764      3.389  8.503e-05 N  1  3.075e-05 -2.527e+03
```

6)

```
netstat -plaunt | egrep "chronyd"
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           36663/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                36663/chronyd
```

Comment: You don't need to put "foo bar +" in the title. That's what we have tags for.